# Determine OS version from an Acronis backup

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, system-restore, acronis-trueimage

I have upgraded to Windows 8, but I'm planning to restore an old Windows 7 backup taken with Acronis.

Unfortunately, my backups are named by date, and not OS.  How can I look at the contents of such a backup to determine if the backup set is for Windows 7 or Windows 8?

Comment: don't you know when (or roughly when) you did a backup? Also, to be clear a **backup** would be very unlikely to restore the OS. An actual **image** of the machine would but it is unlikely that this is what you have.

Comment: Specifically, it is an Acronis Image backup, so it is restorable.  I just have about 6 of them, some of which are Win7 and some are Win8.  I need to find the most recent Win7, hence my question.

Comment: So you don't know when you changed your operating system?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  It was either the 16, 17, 18, 19, etc...

Comment: So restore to the last one. If that isn't it, restore to the next previous, etc. There may be a date in the registry or WMI that indicates when the OS was installed also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have True Image [2012](http://kb.acronis.com/content/33033) or [2013](http://kb.acronis.com/content/34879) installed, you can easily explore your backup images:

1. In Windows Explorer, locate the backup from which you want to restore data, right-click on it and select Open:

   [image: 1]
2. If the backup contains several slices from different dates, select the necessary slice:

   [image: 2]
3. Select the necessary partition:

   [image: 3]
4. You will see the disk contents in the Windows Explorer window. You can copy and paste or drag-and-drop files and folders from the backup to your system:

   [image: 4]
5. As far as identifying the OS goes, I guess you can check the version of **Windows\Explorer.exe**. It should be 6.1.7601 for Windows 7 SP1, and 6.2.9200 for Windows 8.

Comment: +1 A better answer than mine for the literal question asked. I still think mine would be faster/easier to solve the underlying issue though :)

Comment: @EBGreen: True, but if he's unsure even after identifying the install date then this might help nail it rather than restoring multiple times unnecessarily.

Comment: I was referring to my **answer** of determining the install date. Not my **comment** to try different restores.

Comment: @EBGreen: Just to generalise this: Suppose someone backed up their systems twice on the same day - once when it had Win7 and once after installing Win8+apps. How would determining the Win8 install date enable them to determine 100% which backup image is for which OS? Note that the backup image's creation/access date can very easily change if it is copied/moved etc. So IMO the best way to confirm would be to actually look *inside*.

Comment: Because unless they could have the same OS installed at one millisecond, they would be able to determine which backup was before the install of the new OS and which was after.

Comment: Ooops...I went back and looked. You are right. If they could do the OS install **and** a new backup in less than ***one second*** (not one miilisecond as I implied in my last comment) then there could be some ambiguity as to which backup has which OS. I find that scenario to be unlikely though.

Comment: But as I noted above, what if the backup images have had their times updated after a simple copy/move? If the dates haven't changed it should be fine, but I just don't think it's a foolproof method where you can be 100% certain.

Comment: @Karan - Unless the user updated those images that wouldn't be possible.  Furthermore based on the fact they have 5 versions/seperate ( doesn't really matter ) backup images the oldest one is Windows 7.

Comment: @Ramhound: "Unless the user updated those images that wouldn't be possible." *What* wouldn't be possible? Moving/copying files in Windows can indeed update the creation/access dates. The modification dates should ordinarily remain constant unless something specifically updates all the file timestamps (as you said, mounting and updating the image will likely do this). Anyway it's all an academic discussion as the user's issue seems to have been solved. :)

Answer (score 1):

In windows 8, open powershell then run this command:

```
[Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime((gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem).InstallDate)
```

That will tell you when W8 was installed. I realize this doesn't answer the specific question that was asked, but it should solve your actual issue.